# Math.min throw Nan

Tags: javascript, math

Hello im trying to use Math.min but i am getting NaN as a result, this is the code.

**method using Math.min**

```
method() {

var DeltaPrueba = this._markerService.getDeltasRx1();
console.log(DeltaPrueba);  // 1
var menor = Math.min(DeltaPrueba);
console.log(menor);  //1

}
```

**Service**

```
CalculateDeltas(){
/* do some math to calculate then save in array Deltas*/

Deltas  = [DeltaT1,DeltaT2,DeltaT3,DeltaT4,DeltaT1CR,DeltaT2CR,DeltaT3CR,DeltaT4CR] ;   
}

 getDeltasRx1(){
        return Deltas;
    }
```

Console log number 1 show the array with all de data like this:

["18.20", "0.00", "425.97", "316.87", "667.80", "422.34", "425.99", "316.89"]

Console log number 2 show the NaN :

NaN

Comment: Because you are not using it properly see the [doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/min)

Comment: Some of the values could not be converted to a Number, read the docs of Math.min

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to do the following

```js
var array = ["18.20", "0.00", "425.97", "316.87", "667.80", "422.34", "425.99", "316.89"];
var min = Math.min.apply(Math, array);
console.log(min);
```

To convert the whole array from strings to numbers you can do `array.map(Number)` but this won't have any impact on getting the min value, as behind the scenes javascript will convert each of these strings to numbers.

Comment: works on strings... https://jsfiddle.net/a2rsb0k6/

Comment: @litelite you linked to an empty fiddle

Comment: @Amy oups, forgot to save. I have edited my comment

Comment: @litelite good shout, well spotted

Comment: but, how can i convert the complete array ?

Comment: `array.map(Number)`

Comment: @IxamDeirf see updated answer